# screen shot using media projection not perfoming any action

Tags: android, screenshot, android-mediaprojection, foreground-service

hi everyone i have a sample screenshot project from (@commonsware) using media project to perform a screen shot in any screen (running in foreground service mode with notification)

however its not taking any picture and just beeping on button click

also my approach is to change the directory but don't know how
i need to change it cause i want to load all images in a recyclerview inside app

any help will appreciated

here's the whole service code:

```
public class ScreenShotService extends Service {
private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 9906;
static final String EXTRA_RESULT_CODE = "resultCode";
static final String EXTRA_RESULT_INTENT = "resultIntent";
static final String ACTION_RECORD = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".RECORD";
static final String ACTION_SHUTDOWN = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".SHUTDOWN";
static final int VIRT_DISPLAY_FLAGS = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
private MediaProjection projection;
private VirtualDisplay vdisplay;
final private HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread(getClass().getSimpleName(), android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
private Handler handler;
private WindowManager windowManager;
private MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager;
private int resultCode;
private Intent resultData;
final private ToneGenerator beeper = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 100);

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
    windowManager = (WindowManager)getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    handlerThread.start();
    handler=new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getAction() == null) {
        resultCode = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_RESULT_CODE, 1337);
        resultData = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_RESULT_INTENT);
        foregroundify();
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_RECORD)) {
        if (resultData!=null) {
            startCapture();
        }
        else {
            Intent ui=
                    new Intent(this, Main.class)
                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            startActivity(ui);
        }
    }
    else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SHUTDOWN)) {
        beeper.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_NACK);
        stopForeground(true);
        stopSelf();
    }

    return(START_NOT_STICKY);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    stopCapture();

    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("Binding not supported. Go away.");
}

WindowManager getWindowManager() {
    return(windowManager);
}

Handler getHandler() {
    return(handler);
}

void processImage(final byte[] png) {
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {File output=new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),
                    "screenshot.png");
            try {

                FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(output);
                fos.write(png);
                fos.flush();
                fos.getFD().sync();
                fos.close();

                MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(ScreenShotService.this,
                        new String[] {output.getAbsolutePath()},
                        new String[] {"image/png"},
                        null);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Exception writing out screenshot", e);
            }
        }
    }.start();

    beeper.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_PROP_ACK);
    stopCapture();
}

private void stopCapture() {
    if (projection!=null) {
        projection.stop();
        vdisplay.release();
        projection=null;
    }
}

private void startCapture() {
    projection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, resultData);
    ImageTransmogrifier it = new ImageTransmogrifier(this);

    MediaProjection.Callback cb = new MediaProjection.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            vdisplay.release();
        }
    };

    vdisplay=projection.createVirtualDisplay("shooter",
            it.getWidth(), it.getHeight(),
            getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi,
            VIRT_DISPLAY_FLAGS, it.getSurface(), null, handler);
    projection.registerCallback(cb, handler);
}

private void foregroundify() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

    builder.setAutoCancel(true)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    builder.setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.rec_icon)
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.app_name));

    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_record_white_24dp,
            getString(R.string.notify_record),
            buildPendingIntent(ACTION_RECORD));

    builder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_eject_white_24dp,
            getString(R.string.notify_shutdown),
            buildPendingIntent(ACTION_SHUTDOWN));

    startForeground(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());
}

private PendingIntent buildPendingIntent(String action) {
    Intent i=new Intent(this, getClass());

    i.setAction(action);

    return(PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, i, 0));
}
```

}

and also imagetransmofrifier class:

```
public class ImageTransmogrifier implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
private final int width;
private final int height;
private final ImageReader imageReader;
private final ScreenShotService svc;
private Bitmap latestBitmap=null;

ImageTransmogrifier(ScreenShotService svc) {
    this.svc=svc;

    Display display=svc.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size=new Point();

    display.getSize(size);

    int width=size.x;
    int height=size.y;

    while (width*height > (2<<19)) {
        width=width>>1;
        height=height>>1;
    }

    this.width=width;
    this.height=height;

    imageReader=ImageReader.newInstance(width, height,
            PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(this, svc.getHandler());
}

@Override
public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    final Image image=imageReader.acquireLatestImage();

    if (image!=null) {
        Image.Plane[] planes=image.getPlanes();
        ByteBuffer buffer=planes[0].getBuffer();
        int pixelStride=planes[0].getPixelStride();
        int rowStride=planes[0].getRowStride();
        int rowPadding=rowStride - pixelStride * width;
        int bitmapWidth=width + rowPadding / pixelStride;

        if (latestBitmap == null ||
                latestBitmap.getWidth() != bitmapWidth ||
                latestBitmap.getHeight() != height) {
            if (latestBitmap != null) {
                latestBitmap.recycle();
            }

            latestBitmap=Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapWidth,
                    height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        latestBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

        if (image != null) {
            image.close();
        }

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap cropped=Bitmap.createBitmap(latestBitmap, 0, 0,
                width, height);

        cropped.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);

        byte[] newPng=baos.toByteArray();

        svc.processImage(newPng);
    }
}

Surface getSurface() {
    return(imageReader.getSurface());
}

int getWidth() {
    return(width);
}

int getHeight() {
    return(height);
}

void close() {
    imageReader.close();
}
```

}

Comment: "however its not taking any picture" -- how are you determining this? Where are you looking for the images? If you run my sample app without modification, does it work?

Comment: hey there @CommonsWare i'm running absolutely the pure code without even a single modification but there is no png file in storage (i searched everywhere)

Comment: "i'm running absoloutley the pure code without even a single modification" -- your code definitely has modifications. I wrote [the code that you started with](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.8/MediaProjection/andshooter). I have never in my life written an activity named `Main`, and you changed other values as well. So, I will ask again: if you run my sample app **without modification**, does it work? If not, what device model are you testing on, and what is in the foreground at the time you are capturing the image?

Comment: @CommonsWare i wrote in the header that i'm trying to take and retrieve them in recyclerview and it means i changed the activity name to my own project and when i say i didn't modify any thing it means i didn't modify any important thing (in imagetransmogrifier or anything that i even dont know what they are) ,i expanding the notification and just clicking on record and nothing but a beep it even not collapsing status bar as i expected, im running it on a huwawei mate10,i already test your project and that doesn't worked too

Comment: "in imagetransmogrifier or anything that i even dont know what they are" -- that is covered in [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), in the chapter on the media projection APIs. Beyond that, use `adb shell` to see if the file is written to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and use the debugger to step through the `run()` method of the `Thread` inside `processImage()` to see if that code is getting called.

Comment: @CommonsWare i'm not behind my machine so i'll do what you said when i had time and will notify you with results,also sorry for any misunderstanding's and thank's for you'r time

Comment: @CommonsWare hi again i tested the whole project its starting capture and running the section you mentioned but still there's no output i even tried to change dirctory but it gives error Exception writing out screenshot
                                                                             java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0screenshot.png: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: `/storage/emulated/0screenshot.png` is not a valid path.

Comment: @CommonsWare ignor that as i said tha was a test only i wondered wheres the screenshot.png in your default project(where it will be saved?)

Comment: It is stored in [`getExternalFilesDir(null)`, as `screenshot.png`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.8/MediaProjection/andshooter/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/andshooter/ScreenshotService.java#L127-L128). Given that the `applicationId` is `com.commonsware.android.andshooter`, the image should be in `Android/data/com.commonsware.android.andshooter/files/` of [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Comment: That file is supposed to then show up in various places that use the `MediaStore`, including on-device gallery-style apps and desktop operating system file managers. However, when you are running into problems finding the file, use `adb shell` to examine the device filesystem directly, or use the Device File Explorer in Android Studio 3.0+ to browse external storage (try looking in `/storage/emulated/0` or `/sdcard`).

Answer (score 0):

It only works when your hit the record button.[![button][1]][1]. Then you'll be able to find in the directory that author suggested